# Borrar registros duplicados en 2 columnas a la vez dentro de una tabla en SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

En sql server 2008 tengo una tabla Tabla1 con col1, col2 y posición. Tengo que borrar los registros que repitan el valor en col1 y col2 a la vez, es decir:

```
*col1*--*col2*----*Posicion*
1 ------ 1 ----- primera
1  ------ 1  ----- segunda -> Tendría que borrarse
1   ------ 2 ----- tercera
1   ------ 3  ----- tercera
2   ------ 1  ----- cuarta
2   ------ 1  ----- quinta -> Tendría que borrarse
```

He intentado añadir un campo id para poder sacar los registros repetidos con group pero sql server da error al añadir el campo id a la consulta select.

¿Qué sentencia sql podría usar para esto?

Comment: Añade siempre el mensaje de error exacto que obtienes al ejecutar algo. Así mismo, incluye la consulta que ya estás intentando usar.

Comment: ¿Que tipo de dato es `Posicion`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente como en mi sql server 2008 no me permite las funciones ROW_NUMBER() o GROUP() de la forma que necesito lo he conseguido de otra forma:

En lugar de borrar los registros he exportado a otra tabla los registros buenos pero al final ha funcionado todo perfecto, os explico como lo hice por si le sirve de ayuda a alguien.

Primero he echo una copia de la tabla para trabajar con ella:

> select * into tabla1_copia from tabla1

Luego he añadido un campo id (int) para tener un identificador único por fila:

> alter Table tabla1_copia Add id Int Identity(1, 1)

Creo una consulta que me da únicamente los id de los registros no repetidos:

> SELECT MIN(id) as idprueba FROM tabla1_copia GROUP BY COL1, COL2

Creo una tabla nueva con todos los registros no repetidos:

> Select * into tabla1_temp from tabla1_copia where idprueba in ( 
>   SELECT MIN(id) as idprueba FROM tabla1_copia  GROUP BY COL1, COL2 )

Ahora quedaría comprobar que esté todo correcto, borrar la tabla tabla1 y tabla1_copia y para terminar cambiar el nombre de la tabla1_temp a tabla1.

Espero que os sirva de ayuda.

Un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un `CTE` con un `ROWNUMBER` para agruparlos y ordenarlos.

Primero compruebas los datos que debes eliminar

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT col1, col2, Cuantos = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col1, col2)
   FROM Tabla1
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Cuantos > 1
```

y si estás conforme, los eliminas

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT col1, col2, Cuantos = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col1, col2)
   FROM Tabla1
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE Cuantos > 1
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Me salta un error en sql server al ejecutar la linea:
SELECT col1, col2, Cuantos = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col1, col2)
   FROM Tabla1

Que dice:
'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de SQL Server tienes?

Comment: SQL server 2008 versión 8.0.194

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` está desde la edición 2015, así que no deberías tener problemas con ella, prueba a separar con un espacio entre `ROW_NUMBER()` y `OVER`. Yo tengo la edición 2017 y funciona correctamente, no puedo probar con otra.

Comment: También puedes intentar `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col1, col2) as Cuantos`, en vez de `Cuantos = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col1, col2)`

Comment: La sentencia que escribí es: SELECT col1, col2 , Cuantos = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2  ORDER BY col1 , col2 )
 FROM Tabla1
Está bien en principio pero parece q mi versión del sql Server no tiene esa función. De todas formas en 2008 también habría registros duplicados, alguna función tiene que haber, sigo buscando. Gracias Roger

Comment: Probablemente, en la base de datos, tienes un nivel de compatibilidad anterior y por eso no reconoce la función.

Answer (score 0):

Además de row_number, si no he entendido mal tú escenario.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLA1 (COL1 INT, COL2 INT, POSICION INT)
GO
INSERT INTO TABLA1 (COL1, COL2, POSICION)
VALUES
(1,1,1),
(1,1,2),-- BORRAR
(1,2,2),
(1,3,3),
(2,1,4),
(2,1,5);-- BORRAR
GO
```

Para obtener los registros que te quedan.

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, MIN(POSICION) as POSICION
FROM TABLA1
GROUP BY COL1, COL2
ORDER BY COL1, COL2
```

[image: Registros que quieres dejar]

Por tanto tendrías que borrar los registros que no estuviesen en este rango.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT COL1, COL2, MIN(POSICION) as POSICION
    FROM TABLA1
    GROUP BY COL1, COL2
)
SELECT T.*
FROM TABLA1 T LEFT JOIN CTE C 
ON T.COL1 = C.COL1 AND T.COL2 = C.COL2 AND T.POSICION <> C.POSICION
WHERE C.COL1 IS NOT NULL
```

[image: Regs a borrar]

Si estos son los registros a borrar, entonces.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT COL1, COL2, MIN(POSICION) as POSICION
    FROM TABLA1
    GROUP BY COL1, COL2
)

DELETE FROM TABLA1 
FROM TABLA1 T LEFT JOIN CTE C 
ON T.COL1 = C.COL1 AND T.COL2 = C.COL2 AND T.POSICION <> C.POSICION
WHERE C.COL1 IS NOT NULL


(2 filas afectadas)
```

Comment: Buenos días.
Mi estructura es distinta porque el campo posición es varchar y al hacer el max da error.
De todas formas gracias por tu aportación, me has dado una idea y he podido hacerlo de otra manera.